# Can't import fetch_mldata from sklearn.datasets

Tags: python, scikit-learn

My datasets are in `fetch_mldata`. But why is it a problem to import them?

This line of code:

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_mldata
```

Leads to the following error:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'fetch_mldata' from 'sklearn.datasets' (C:\Users\gopak\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\datasets_*init*_.py)

Answer (score 0):

`fetch_mldata` is [deprecated](https://scikit-learn.org/0.20/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.fetch_mldata.html). Use [`fetch_openml`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.fetch_openml.html) instead. E.g. like so:

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_openml
X, y = fetch_openml('mnist_784', return_X_y=True,)
print(X.shape, y.shape)
```